# 400 Bad Request when Sync via Sync Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, microsoft-sync-framework

i try to Sync a Windows Mobile Device with a SqlServer via Sync Framework.

It worked already but now i get a 400 Bad Request and don't know why.

The Service is available and i can open the wsdl in the internetexplorer on the device.

Edit: I use a BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: are you using the Sync Fx v4 CTP or the older SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DBServerSyncProvider?

Comment: I use the older one.
I already found out what happened.
The name of the binding configuration in the binding itself and in the declaration of the configuration where diverent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself:

The name of the binding configuration in the binding itself and in the declaration of the configuration where diverent.